# Issue With Counting Number of Characters in Two Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

The purpose of this function is to compare the number of times a color appears in the code and the number of times it appears in the guess to ultimately determine how many colors were guessed correctly. I am experiencing some errors with my current code, and I believe that the number of lines could be greatly simplified. More specifically, I think I am overcomplicating the task at hand.

Does anyone have a suggestion of a better way to tackle this problem? I am very new to programming and it would be greatly appreciated.

```
validColors = ("R", "G", "B", "Y", "O", "P")

secretCode = "YBGG"
guess = "BYYG"

def correctColorCount(secretCode, guess, validColors):

    count = 0

    numRedGuess = guess.count("R")
    numRedCode = secretCode.count("R")
    sumR = numRedGuess + numRedCode

    numGreenGuess = guess.count("G")
    numGreenCode = secretCode.count("G")
    sumG = numGreenGuess + numGreenCode

    numBlueGuess = guess.count("B")
    numBlueCode = secretCode.count("B")
    sumB = numBlueGuess + numBlueCode

    numYellowGuess = guess.count("Y")
    numYellowCode = secretCode.count("Y")
    sumY = numYellowGuess + numBlueCode

    numOrangeGuess = guess.count("O")
    numOrangeCode = secretCode.count("O")
    sumO = numOrangeGuess + numOrangeCode

    numPurpleGuess = guess.count("P")
    numPurpleCode = secretCode.count("P")
    sumP = numPurpleGuess + numPurpleCode

    if numRedCode == numRedGuess and sumR != 0 and sumR != 1:
        count += 1
        if numRedGuess == 2:
            count += 1
        elif numRedGuess == 3:
            count += 2
        elif numRedGuess == 4:
            count += 3
    elif numRedGuess >= 1 and numRedCode >= 1 and sumR != 0 and sumR != 1:
        count += 1
    if numGreenCode == numGreenGuess and sumG != 0 and sumG != 1:
        count += 1
        if numGreenGuess == 2:
            count += 1
        elif numGreenGuess == 3:
            count += 2
        elif numGreenGuess == 4:
            count += 3
    elif numGreenGuess >= 1 and numGreenCode >= 1 and sumG != 0 and sumG != 1:
        count += 1
    if numBlueCode == numBlueGuess and sumB != 0 and sumB != 1:
        count += 1
        if numBlueGuess == 2:
            count += 1
        elif numBlueGuess == 3:
            count += 2
        elif numBlueGuess == 4:
            count += 3
    elif numBlueGuess >= 1 and numBlueCode >= 1 and sumB != 0 and sumB != 1:
        count += 1
    if numYellowCode == numYellowGuess and sumY != 0 and sumY != 1:
        count += 1
        if numYellowGuess == 2:
            count += 1
        elif numYellowGuess == 3:
            count += 2
        elif numYellowGuess == 4:
            count += 3
    elif numYellowGuess >= 1 and numYellowCode >= 1 and sumY != 0 and sumY != 1:
        count += 1
    if numOrangeCode == numOrangeGuess and sumO != 0 and sumO != 1:
        count += 1
        if numOrangeGuess == 2:
            count += 1
        elif numOrangeGuess == 3:
            count += 2
        elif numOrangeGuess == 4:
            count += 3
    elif numOrangeGuess >= 1 and numOrangeCode >= 1 and sumO != 0 and sumO != 1:
        count += 1
    if numPurpleCode == numPurpleGuess and sumP != 0 and sumP != 1:
        count += 1
        if numPurpleGuess == 2:
            count += 1
        elif numPurpleGuess == 3:
            count += 2
        elif numPurpleGuess == 4:
            count += 3
    elif numPurpleGuess >= 1 and numPurpleCode >= 1 and sumP != 0 and sumP != 1:
        count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: Is this for [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game))?

Comment: It is! Would it be helpful if I included the rest of my program?

Comment: Since Mastermind is about counting elements, try [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which I use in [this Let's Code Python: Mastermind video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hv47MO1vQAo) (25 lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can build up from something like this, using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter


def correct_color_count(secret, guess):
    correct = Counter(secret) & Counter(guess)
    return sum(correct.values())

correct_color_count(secret="YBGG", guess="BYYG")
>>> 3
```

This will give you the count of correct guesses, disregarding position.

Answer (score 1):

assuming we ignore colors missing from both input strings, here is a way:

```
def correctColorCount(secretCode, guess, validColors):
    count = 0
    # for all the color characters
    for color in validColors:
        # if color count is not zero and same for both strings
        if secretCode.count(color) == guess.count(color) != 0:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one way to do it:

```
def countColors(word, colors):
    return (word.count(color) for color in colors)

def correctColorCount(secretCode, guess, colors):
    for index, (guessedColor, correctColor) in enumerate(zip(*map(lambda word: 
        countColors(word, colors), (secretCode, guess)))):
        color = colors[index]
        if guessedColor == correctColor:
            print("You guessed", color, "correctly!")
        else:
            print("You guessed", color, "incorrectly. You guessed", guessedColor, "but it was", str(correctColor) + ".")


>>> validColors = ("R", "G", "B", "Y", "O", "P")
>>> secretCode = "YBGG"
>>> guess = "BYYG"
>>> correctColorCount(secretCode, guess, validColors)
You guessed R correctly!
You guessed G incorrectly. You guessed 2 but it was 1.
You guessed B correctly!
You guessed Y incorrectly. You guessed 1 but it was 2.
You guessed O correctly!
You guessed P correctly!
```

`countColors` will count the number of each color in a word, given a list of colors to count from. This uses a list comprehension.

`correctColorCount` explained:

`map(lambda word: countColors(word, colors), (secretCode, guess))`

This will run countColors with secretCode and guess. Equivalent to writing:

`[countColors(secretCode, colors), countColors(guess, colors)]`

`zip(*....)`

This will take them in pairs: the first one of each, then the second, etc. So, this will essentially create a list for each color:
`[actualNumberOfTimes, guessedNumberOfTimes]`.

`enumerate` is probably easier to understand [here](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a lot of code... Can be simplified to:

```
def correctColorCount(secretCode, guess):
    guess_list = list(guess)
    return len(guess) - sum(1 for color in secretCode 
                            if color not in guess_list or guess_list.remove(color))
```

No additional modules required. `validColors` are not needed for this comparison, you should check against `validColors` when users input their combination.